# Does anyone know the origin of "drawing the bustle" as in spending too much money?

Tags: etymology

I've read it in Georgette Heyer but can't find it elsewhere. Is it an expression she made up?

Comment: Where did you look? 
Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR: Heyer did not coin it; it was a bit of slang used historically, even if rarely.**

Georgette Heyer famously had a huge collection of historical references including private papers, from which she drew to create her distinctive imitation of Regency dialogue (see, for example, [*Wikipedia*'s Heyer article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgette_Heyer#Regency_romances)).

Some of Heyer's "found" phrases, which might have been ephemeral slang or an individual's one-time-only coinage, have since passed from Heyer's work into broader literary usage. To "make a cake of oneself" meaning "embarrass oneself" is an example: it was once used as evidence in an accusation of plagiarism, as a phrase that Heyer originally found in a private memoir and that the other author would only have encountered in Heyer's novels ([*Id*.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgette_Heyer#Imitators)). Heyer did not choose to pursue legal action, however, and it has now become a standard (Regency) romance novel cliché. (See a [Google Ngram of "make a cake of myself here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=make%20a%20cake%20of%20myself&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmake%20a%20cake%20of%20myself%3B%2Cc0), and a [Google Books search of the phrase here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22make%20a%20cake%20of%20myself%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en).

This does not guarantee that phrases found in Heyer's work were all authentically "period"; she apparently also occasionally inserted cant made up from whole cloth (and possibly intentionally mis-used authentic Regency slang) as a way of tripping up her imitators, and her sources may also have gotten things wrong ([Jenny Brown](http://lordsoftheseventhhouse.blogspot.com/2010/01/regency-slang.html), partially citing Jane Aiken Hodge's biography of Heyer, which is also a frequent source of the above-cited *Wikipedia* article).

In this particular case, following Brown's practice of browsing nineteenth century dictionaries via Google Books turns up your phrase:

> BUSTLE, money; "to draw the bustle" (*[A Dictionary of Modern Slang, Cant, And, Vulgar Words: Preceded by a History of Cant and Vulgar Language : with Glossaries of Two Secret Languages](https://books.google.com/books?id=XCRKAAAAcAAJ&dq=slang%20or%20cant&pg=PA109#v=onepage&q=bustle&f=false)* by John C. Hotten, 1860)

[image: Hotten's Dictionary of slang image]

So Heyer did not make up the phrase. But how commonly it was used in the nineteenth century and earlier is certainly open to question, and it is likely that any usage in the past seventy years is due to her influence.

Comment: Interestingly, Hotten seems to have picked up the expression, whole cloth, from a brief mention by Cuthbert Bede of "a few words omitted from Mr. Hotten's _Dictionary_" of 1859: "_Bustle_, money—"draw the bustle." See "[Modern Slang, Cant, and Vulgar Words](https://books.google.com/books?id=8Eo6PLHz8JsC&pg=PA493&dq=%22draw+the+bustle%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiDvtyP05eAAxVwjIkEHcAVBAcQ6AF6BAgNEAI#v=onepage&q=%22draw%20the%20bustle%22&f=false)" in _Notes and Queries_ (December 17, 1859) for Bede's full comment on the first edition of Hotten's dictionary.

Comment: The current, online, OED dates the cant to "1763   Proc. Old Bailey 4 May 32/1   *He had got the bustle (meaning the cash) in his pocket.* and marks it as obsolete. The 1989 version does not mention obsolete. There are enough examples to give the impression that, in the late 18th and to the mid-19th century, it had currency.

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes most likely she coined the phrase.

Based only on worldwide usage. That in the whole of Google, there are only seven pages matched for the phrase (and I just counted six of them reference Gergette Heyer in some way) and the seventh is sombody 'drawing the [hustle] bustle' in a picture.